# How to define a class in php using a variable as class name?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to define multiple classes for via `for loop` as seen below:

```
for ($i = 2; $i < 4 ; $i++) {
            
    $class_name = 'Class_' . $i;        
    
    class $class_name {
    
    public $action;
        
    }
}
```

However, the code gives syntax error. How to define classes using variables in php?

Comment: classes dont tend to be dynamic they are thought out and designed to fulfil a function before hand, what are you trying to achieve by trying to do this

Comment: How would you *use* a dynamically named class?  Why do you need one?  This sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: I think it's a bad practice. Think more for to find a better way to fix your issue.

Comment: I am trying to extend a background processing plugin which requires multiple classes to be created as per batch size due to memory limits.

Comment: Sounds like a class (predefined) with some properties that can be set to control whatever

Comment: @dc09: You can store the definition of classes in separate PHP files, and [include()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) those files when they are needed. That's how PHP normally works.

Comment: Why would you need multiple variably named classes that are functionally identical? Any reason you can't just create multiple instances of the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not a good idea, as it can make your code unstable and insecure.  However, if you really want to do this you might use `eval()`

```
$class_name = 'Class_' . $i;
eval('   
    class ' . $class_name . ' {
    
    public $action;
        
    }
');
```

Comment: Correct, its not :)

Comment: Be very careful when you have eval() in your system . Make sure it is not exposed to any data injection.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I [tested something similar to this code](https://3v4l.org/QTjW7) and it does work. It could even be safe when you know what you're doing ... but `eval()` is certainly not loved. I've written a lot of Lisp in my days, and that language is solely based on an "eval()" function, every language is, in the end.

Comment: @Kiko My comment was aimed at "_This is probably not a good idea_" rather than _it wont work_

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Haha, ok. Perhaps I didn't expect it to work, and took your comment as a confirmation. I never use `eval()`, and was a bit surprised it could do this.